# How to output a regression table with dependent variables as columns in R?

Tags: r, output, regression, stargazer

I am trying to replicate the following table from Angrist and Evans (1998):

[image]

Each cell in this table is a different regression and I am only interested on one coefficient for each regression. I have estimated all variations with `ivreg()` in R successfully. However, I need to output this table in LATEX format.

In principle, I'd use `stargazer`. But it seems that its `flip` flag only works for tables. For example:

```
mymodel <- lm(displ ~ cty, data = mpg)
mymodel2 <- lm(displ ~ cty + hwy, data = mpg)
stargazer(mymodel, mymodel2, keep = 'cty', flip = TRUE, type = 'text', keep.stat = 'n')
```

This will output the following table:

```
=========================================
                 Dependent variable:     
             ----------------------------
                        displ            
                  (1)            (2)     
-----------------------------------------
cty            -0.242***      -0.233***  
                (0.012)        (0.041)   
                                         
-----------------------------------------
Observations      234            234     
=========================================
Note:         *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

I would like to have only one column and two rows in this case, for instance. What would be a good way to output results in latex format? Any other package other than stargazer?

Comment: Note that you shouldn’t use ‘stargazer’, because [‘stargazer’ is an utterly atrocious package](https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/6o9v9h/whats_your_favorite_relatively_obscure_r_package/dkgw9q1/). Use ‘[modelsummary](https://cran.r-project.org/package=modelsummary)’ or ‘[texreg](https://cran.r-project.org/package=texreg)’ instead, or *literally anything else*.